# Is it possible to get the live preview of the Insta360 One X camera using Open Spherical Camera API?

Tags: api

I am trying to get live preview from insta360 One X using a Chrome browser. I have tried with some commands like 192.168.42.1/osc/info. It is responding. But I don't know how to see the live feed from the camera. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Please add more tags like , Camera API, Insta360, Chrome

Comment: can you please share the api rewuest you are sending

Answer (score 0):

You can see here the documentation preview stream is not supported for their implementation of OSC:
https://github.com/Insta360Develop/CameraSDK-iOS